# How to send website status and report to customer on socail media such as line/msg by using javascript on dialogflow?

Tags: javascript, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am newbie dialogflow. I want to create the message that tell user that server is online or not.
Please help me... Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can make and intent with some message like `Server, Are You Online?` and give response for this intent from webhook and set default response to "Server Not Available". In this way if server will not be available then default response will be server is offline, Otherwise you can catch intent on webhook and send response according to you.
I think this might help you.

Comment: So I confuse... I link with webhook already (I have only URL). How can I use web status? to report back to user on line?

Comment: Can I get the status how much you have worked out on dialogflow? So that I can tell you what you can do next that may help you..